# A bag has 55 counters, marked 1 to 55. A person draws a counter at random receives this amount in money. find the expected value of the amount?

Tags: probability

I just cant understand this question.

its different to a lot of probability questions I've done.

need some help.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ denote the amount he gets.

Then $P(X=i)=1/55$ for $1 \leq i \leq 55$.

So, $E(X)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{55}k*1/55$. Now just find this sum .

Comment: how do you do this some on the calculator quickly? surely you don't have to add up each one?

Comment: @user141626: nope. Hint: $1+2+..+n=n(n+1)/2$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Expected value= $\sum_{x=1}^{55}x. \frac 1{55}$